Mapping packets mark to internal Linux priority in PRIO Qdisc
I am trying PRIO qdisc.
tc qdisc add dev <interface> root handle 1:0 prio bands 3
tc qdisc add dev <interface> parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq
tc qdisc add dev <interface> parent 1:2 handle 20: sfq
tc qdisc add dev <interface> parent 1:3 handle 30: sfq

I have marked the packets like below, using iptables.
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i <interface> -p udp --dport xxxx -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport yyyy -j MARK --set-mark 2

From https://linux-tc-notes.sourceforge.net/tc/doc/sch_prio.txt:
priomap classForPrio_0 classForPrio_1 ... classForPrio_15

I want to set packets with mark-1 to handle 10 and mark-2 to handle 20 and the rest to handle 30.
How can I achieve that. Please help.
